# How to script custom Openfire IQ request in tsung

Tags: erlang, openfire, stress-testing, tsung

My IQ request is

```
<iq id="rn3Nd-0" to="servername@domain.com" type="set">
  <query xmlns="my:xmlns:name">
     <username>someuser</username>
  </query>
</iq>
```

How do I customize tsung scripts to bombard my openfire with above IQ request. Value in username has to be dynamic and keep changing. I would like to create 1000 request in a minute. How can we achieve this in tsung script.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the usernames from a CSV file. So if you need 100 users you can create a CSV of 1000 names and it will randomly pick names from that.

http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-sessions.html#reading-usernames-and-password-from-a-csv-file